# I want to use The GATE Predicate-Argument EXtractor Component (PAX)

Tags: nlp, gate, pax

I want to use The GATE Predicate-Argument EXtractor Component (PAX), but I can't figure out how to load the plugin on GATE developer (ver. 7)

Please help me.
How do I load it?

Comment: just i don't know how to load it.

Answer (score 0):

The MultiPaX plugin is a bit of a complex beast.  You need to download the package from [the homepage](http://www.semanticsoftware.info/pax), unpack it (use something like [7-zip](http://7-zip.com) if you're on Windows) and then build it using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org), which you will need to install separately - GATE used to bundle a copy of Ant but that is no longer the case since version 7.  Once you have the plugin compiled and packaged you should be able to load it through the plugin manager the same as any other plugin.

However, to get anything useful out of the PR you need to build quite a complex pipeline including at least one of SUPPLE, MiniPar or the Stanford Parser PR.  Getting these to work is itself a non-trivial task...

The predicate argument extractor is not developed by the core GATE team, so specific questions are probably better posted in the semanticsoftware.info forum (linked from the bottom of http://www.semanticsoftware.info/pax) rather than the usual GATE user list.